# Send State Value From Component to another Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a tabs using react

i have a file that contain the data info it's an array of object
this array of object contain id,title,info,pic,category

I have a component named Buttons this component show all the category in the array of object with a button named All

```
export default function Buttons() {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState("all");
  const switchTab = (curcat) => {
    setTab(curcat);
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <Span className="active">all</Span>
      {data.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <Span key={i} onClick={() => switchTab(item)}>
            {item}
          </Span>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

In another component called Portfolio I call the Buttons component and i show all the data in the array of object using the map function

in this component i made a function to filter the data depend on the category and then show the results using the map function
the code below work but it's not dynamic i want to put instead of web design the value from the Buttons component to make it dynamic so when i click on a button i show all content that have this category and if i click all i show every thing

```
export default function Portfolio() {
    const filtered = data.filter(profile => {
        return profile.category === "web design";
      });

  return (
    <div id='profile'>
    <PortfolioWrapper>
        <Buttons />
        <ProfileContainer>
        {
          
          filtered.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <ProfileBox 
                        key={item.id}
                        title={item.title}
                        info={item.info}
                        pic={item.pic}
                    />
                )
            })
        }
        </ProfileContainer>
    </PortfolioWrapper>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manage the state in `Portfolio` component

```
export default function Portfolio() {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("all");
  const filtered = data.filter(profile => {
    return category === "all" || profile.category === category
  });

  return (
    <div id='profile'>
      <PortfolioWrapper>
        <Buttons value={category} onClick={setCategory} />
        <ProfileContainer>
        {    
          filtered.map((item) => (
            <ProfileBox 
              key={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              info={item.info}
              pic={item.pic}
            />
          )
        }
        </ProfileContainer>
      </PortfolioWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function Buttons({value, onClick}) {  
  return (
    <>
      <Span 
        className={value === "all" ? "active" : ""} 
        onClick={() => onClick("all")}
      >
        all
      </Span>
      {data.map(item => {
        return (
          <Span 
           key={item} 
           className={value === item ? "active" : ""}
           onClick={() => onClick(item)}
          >
            {item}
          </Span>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```